# Need to change User Pages Title and Breadcrumb in drupal 7?

Tags: users, breadcrumbs, 7, routes

I want to change Title and breadcrumb for user pages to `username` to `My Account`.
I don't want to user `drupal_set_title` or `drupal_set_breadcrumb` bcoz its in lots of pages

I saw below code in `user core module`

```
  $items['user/%user'] = array(
        'title' => 'My account',
        'title callback' => 'user_page_title',
        'title arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'user_view_page',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => 'user_view_access',
        'access arguments' => array(1),
        // By assigning a different menu name, this item (and all registered child
        // paths) are no longer considered as children of 'user'. When accessing the
        // user account pages, the preferred menu link that is used to build the
        // active trail (breadcrumb) will be found in this menu (unless there is
        // more specific link), so the link to 'user' will not be in the breadcrumb.
        'menu_name' => 'navigation',
      );

/**
 * Menu item title callback - use the user name.
 */
function user_page_title($account) {
  return is_object($account) ? format_username($account) : '';
}
```

User menu is calling title callback function and set the user name in that callback function. So i have tried `hook_menu_alter` to change title callback of user menu but it is not working

My Code

```
function health_portal_menu_alter(&$items) { 
  $items['user/%user']['title callback'] = 'health_portal_user_menu_title';
}

function health_portal_user_menu_title() {
  return 'Test';
}
```

Anybody tell me what is wrong with this code and what i do?

Thanks

Comment: Did you clear the cache after implementing the hook?

Comment: Yes i had tried with clear cache. but it did not work

Comment: Ok next thing to check would be if the menu_router database table contains the modified entries. Your code looks correct, so you need to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to implement through code, give a try to these modules:

https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title

https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs